# If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$, then find $f(2021)+f(1971)+f(50)$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

I came across this question while solving a compendium of previous year questions of regional Mathematics Olympiads.
If $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $f(f(x))=x^2-x+1$, then find $f(2021)+f(1971)+f(50)$.

I have proceeded till finding out: $$f(0)=f(1)=1$$ $$f(1-x)=f(x)$$
I proceeded like this:$$f(f(f(x)))=(f(x))^2-f(x)+1$$
This implies that $f(f(f(1)))=(f(1))^2-f(1)+1$.
Now $f(f(1))=1$ therefore $f(1)=(f(1))^2-f(1)+1$ which is why $f(1)=1$.
Next I proved that $f(f(1-x)=f(x)$ using the fact that $$f(f(x)=(x-\dfrac{1}{2})^2+\dfrac{3}{4}$$
Then I proved that $f(x)$ is symmetric along $\dfrac{1}{2}$.
Next we put $x=\dfrac{1}{2}-x$ in the equations $f(\dfrac{1}{2}-x)=f(\dfrac{1}{2}+x)$ since it is valid for all values of x.
That is how I got $f(0)=f(1)=1$ and $f(1-x)=f(x)$.
But how do I proceed further to find the value of $f(2021)+f(1971)+f(50)$?

Comment: It seems you have deleted your previous question and asked the same question again...

Comment: yeah because it was closed and i could not understand why.

Comment: btw can you please show me how you got $\sum_{1}^n f(n_i)>n, ∀n_i∈(1,∞)$?

Comment: I don't understand why $f(x) = f(1-x)$

Comment: Deleting and reposting is against the site rules. You should have edited that first post. May be adding the reasoning you give here to it would have sufficed? I cannot tell for sure because you deleted the question, but may be not having such details was the reason it was closed?

Comment: Anyway, having too many closed (other than duplicates) and deleted questions may lead to a (non-negotiable) post-ban. It is better to prevent that from ever happening, surely. Check out [our abridged guide for new askers](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35391/11619) to learn about the expectations.

Comment: @SwagBeastSKJJ I do not know the answer. Would you mind sharing what you have done and how you have proceeded with the sum?